# Under defined sketch - inner rectangle for chessboard

Tags: solidworks

I am working on chess board using `SolidWorks 2016` and I've created two rectangles, outer one and inner one with `8x8` grid using `Linear Sketch Pattern`:
[image]Why is my sketch **under defined**?

**ADDENDUM**:
It seems I've managed to manage relations of inner rectangle - **I've added dimensions between lines and added `Perpendicular` relation to base two lines in centre of coordinate system** - so I think now it is fully defined, however, whole sketch is still **under defined**:
[image]
Why?

Comment: You have way too many dimensions, you should use less dimensions and more relations for starters. try starting with a rectangle centred on the origin - set two touchings sides as equal and dimension any side 700. draw another smaller square, same centre, set as construction, dimension 15 smaller than the other square. You now have the two outer squares fully defined and only needed two dimensions -much tidier and easier to manage.

Comment: @Fergus is right about best practices. I believe that in SW blue means that an element is not fully defined, so it looks like your letters across the bottom might be where you are under constrained. try dimensioning the y location for them they x location aligned with the midpoints above them.

Comment: And if in doubt, click 'fully define sketch' and SW will add whatever dimensions are required to fully define the sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. I've deleted all relations and then selected `Display/Delete Relations->Fully define sketch`.

Comment: This is bad practice. Solidworks automatic fully define sketch feature is very "dumb", and using it is a lazy approach. it generally just adds lots and lots of dimensions which can destroy the intent of the sketch/make changes very difficult. Best to use more relations and fewer dimensions. My suggestion to use the fully define sketch feature was just to see where SW would add dimensions, then "undo", and add your own, more appropriate dimensions and relations.